# Node.js local response vs integration (running on docker and envoy) response is different

Tags: node.js, express

I found that while invoking same rest api from postman the body of response seems to be the same but response status message is different for localhost vs integration (same code is deployed to integration and running locally. I have attached pics [["Internal server error" is one in integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DT9A.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nxs.png))

I am dumb founded why response status message is different(internal server error vs no html found) and response body is same even when the source code is same. I have added logging but nothing seems out of place.

Adding a picture for more context [comparision between localhost and integration server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPoXa.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.